# Maximum value of linear combination of sinusoids

Tags: trigonometry, optimization, numerical-methods

Given a sequence of integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, is there a way to calculate the maximum value of the following function?
$$f(\theta) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cos(j \theta)$$
More specifically, I need to know whether $f(\theta)$ ever exceeds a given value $N$. I expect this to be true for most of the sequences being tested.

My approach so far has been to simply evaluate the function at 101 different points $\theta = 0, \frac\pi{100}, \dots, \frac{99\pi}{100}, \pi$. The maximum result, $M$, is a lower bound on the maximum value of $f$, and I simply test whether $M \gt N$.

The benefit of this approach is that it can't give a false positive (if $M > N$, then $f$ certainly exceeds $N$ at some point). But is there an alternative (with similar computational complexity) that could give a tighter lower-bound - and hence reduce the likelihood of a false negative ($M <= N$ but $f$ still exceeds $N$ somewhere)?

**Edit:** Newton's Method, as described below, is a definite improvement over the above approach. I tested using a set of 100,000 sequences of length 20, for all of which the function $f$ exceeds $N$ at some point.

Evaluating $f$ at 100 points, as above, was sufficient to confirm that $N$ is exceeded in 99.6% of cases. Reducing the number of evaluations to 25 took only 30% as much time, but could only confirm 92.6%. Using 25 evaluations and Newton's Method, however, confirmed 99.7% in 50% of the time.

Are there other methods, similar to Newton's or otherwise, that might improve things further? Perhaps something specific to sinusoidal functions?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating and finding maximums? Even just by evaluation (since I assume that you are using a computer this should be very easy).

Comment: If you want to be sure to not miss any maximum, expand trigonometric functions using tchebychev polynomials, differentiate, do a variable change to get a polynomial, apply a root finding algorithm on [-1, 1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_root-finding_algorithms, then search for the maximum value by considering all roots

Comment: You can probably speed up your calculation by using the Fast Fourier Transform. For a probabilistic approach, see *Benke, George, and W. J. Hendricks. "Estimates for large deviations in random trigonometric polynomials." SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis 24.4 (1993): 1067-1085.*.

Comment: If you just need an upper bound, then the largest magnitude of the eigenvalues of the circulant matrix made of $a_i$ could give you a bound.

Comment: @Yimin - An upper bound that's easy to compute would be useful, because if it's `<= N` for a given sequence it would avoid the need to do more work with that sequence. However for most sequences, the function will exceed `N` at some point - so a lower bound for `max(f)` would be more useful than an upper bound.

Comment: Maybe you could exploit the [stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation)

Answer (score 1):

We can estimate and adjust the precision of your approach using Lagrange's theorem. Namely, given a natural number $M$, put $P=\left\{0,\tfrac{\pi}{M},\tfrac{2\pi}M,\dots,\tfrac{M\pi}M\right\}$. Suppose that we evaluated the values of $f$ at the points of $P$ and $N'$ is the maximum of these values.
Now let $\theta\in [0,\pi]\setminus P$ be any point. Then there exists a point $\theta_0\in P$ such that
$|\theta-\theta_0|\le \tfrac{\pi}{2M}$. By Lagrange's theorem, there exists a point $\eta$ between $\theta$ and $\theta_0$ such that $f(\theta)-f(\theta_0)=f'(\eta)(\theta-\theta_0)$. Put $L=\sum_{j=1}^n j|a_j|$. Then $f'(\eta)\le L$, so $f(\theta)\le f(\theta_0)+\tfrac{\pi L}{2M}\le N'+\tfrac{\pi L}{2M}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Slight Modification**

We define $\theta=2\pi\cdot t$. We want to obtain the maximum of the function

$$
f(2\pi\cdot t)=
\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_{m}\cdot\cos\left(2\pi m\cdot t\right)
$$

When dealing with sum of harmonics, the first thing that comes to mind is one of the most important algorithm of all time: the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) and its inverse. The coefficients $a_{m}$ are the FFT results of $f(2\pi\cdot t)$ so we just need to perform the inverse FFT.

**Implementation**

The following is a Python script that perform the inverse FFT on the coefficients, with some scaling due to Numpy's implementation of the algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sampling frequency i.e. resolution
fs = 10000

# suffice to evaluate one period
t = np.arange(0, 1, 1/fs)

# number of cosines and coefficients
coeffs = [1, 5, 3, 4]
nCoeffs = len(coeffs)

# put coefficients into the frequency vector
fft_result = np.zeros(len(t))
fft_result[[1+i for i in range(nCoeffs)]] = [fs * coeff for coeff in coeffs]

# inverse FFT to obtain the actual function
signal = np.fft.ifft(fft_result)

plt.plot(t, signal.real, label=f'Max Value: {np.max(signal.real)}')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will output

[image: Python Script Output]

In the script I use $a=\{1, 5, 3, 4\}$ as an example. You can change it to your specific needs. Another parameter you can change is the resolution, the higher it is the closer we are to the real maxima.
The inverse FFT algorithm has a complexity of $\mathcal{O}\left(n\log\left(n\right)\right)$

**Advantage**

When the number of coefficients is large, the number of local maxima can be large too. For example, the following is the sum of $1000$ cosines where the coefficients are uniform random variables between $-10$ and $10$:

[image: Erratic Function]

As you can imagine, Newton-like methods will struggle to get even close to the global maxima in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**Too long for comment.**

*Remark*: Perhaps the result below is not helpful in practice.

1. Assume $a_n \ne 0$.
   $$N - \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cos j\theta \ge 0, \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$
   if and only if there exist real numbers $c_k, k=0, 1, 2, \cdots, n$ such that
   \begin{align*}
    2N &= \sum_{k=0}^n c_k^2, \\
    -a_k &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} c_{k+i}c_i, \quad k=1, 2, \cdots, n.
   \end{align*}

See: Theorem 4, [1].

2. Assume $a_n \ne 0$.
   If
   $$N - \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \cos j\theta \ge 0, \quad \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R},$$
   then
   $$\frac{|a_k|}{2N} \le \cos \frac{\pi}{\lfloor n/k\rfloor + 2}, \quad k = 1, 2, \cdots, n.$$

See: Theorem 6, [1].

---

Consider an example $n=5$.

I) We ask if
$3\cos x + 2\cos 2x - \cos 3x - 2\cos 4x + 5\cos 5x \le 7.01$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
According to 1), it holds if and only if there exist real numbers $c_0, c_1, \cdots, c_5$ such that
\begin{align*}
 2\cdot \frac{701}{100} &= c_0^2 + c_1^2 + c_2^2 + c_3^2 + c_4^2 + c_5^2, \\
 -3 &= c_1c_0 + c_2c_1 + c_3c_2 + c_4c_3 + c_5c_4, \\
 -2 &= c_2c_0 + c_3c_1 + c_4c_2 + c_5c_3,\\
 1 &= c_3c_0 + c_4c_1 + c_5c_2,\\
 2 &= c_4c_0 + c_5c_1, \\
 -5 &= c_5c_0.
\end{align*}
*Maple* fsolve tells us that the system has a real solution.

II) We ask if $3\cos x + 2\cos 2x - \cos 3x - 2\cos 4x + 5\cos 5x \le 4.9$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?
According to 2), the answer if no.

$\phantom{2}$

*Reference.*
[1] "Extremal Positive Trigonometric Polynomials", [https://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/~dimitrov/papers/main.pdf](https://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/%7Edimitrov/papers/main.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

If only a rough upper bound needed, other than the trivial bound $\sum |a_i|$, you can evaluate $f$ at $e^{2\pi j i/ n}$ and find the supremum, then multiply $\sqrt{n}$ as a bound, but that maybe is still far from optimal. But it is easy to compute.

Let $A$ be the circulant matrix made by $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$, see the definition on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix).

Then your function $|f(\theta)|$ is less than the magnitude of the first element in $A v := A [1, e^{i\theta},\cdots, e^{(n-1)\theta}]^T$, because $A$ can be diagonalized with discrete Fourier transform matrices, thus

$\sup |f|\le \|A v\|_{L^2} \le \rho(A) \|v\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{n} \rho(A)$, where $\rho(A)$ is the maximum value at $|f(e^{2j \pi i/n})|$, $j=0,\cdots, n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Newton's Method**

Instead of evaluating $f$ at 100 arbitrary points, try making a smaller number of arbitrary evaluations and then using [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) on $f'$ to evaluate at some more informed points.

For example, as well as evaluating $f$ at each point $\theta$, also perform a single iteration of Newton's Method by evaluating $f$ at $\theta - f'(\theta) / f''(\theta)$. The latter should be closer to a zero of $f'$ than $\theta$ and, if $f''(\theta) < 0$, closer to a local maximum of $f$. This should increase the chance of finding a point where $f$ exceeds the value $N$.

Since this method increases the number of evaluations at each point from a single evaluation of $f$ to two of $f$, one of $f'$ and one of $f''$ it requires four times as much computation per point - so to keep similar amount of computation overall, reduce the number of points from 100 to 25.